# How can I disable Jetpack Compose previews on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I want to disable all Jetpack Compose previews at once.
Is there any Android Studio config for that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if there's a specific option for that, but you can (by default) open a "Compose File" without showing the preview.

This option is available in Preferences > Editor > Design Tools.

[image]

Comment: Previously there was a button in the preview window to show hide it. now its not there, but this hides it completely